# git revert several specific commits

Tags: git, conflict, revert, git-revert

The problem: A branch has good commits interleaved with undesired ones.

Attempted solution:

```
git revert hash5 hash8 hash9 hash23
```

What I thought this would do is that it'd apply all specified commits, and then let me sort out any conflicts.

What I now think that happens:

- git applies commit hash5, in the process introducing large conflicts.
- I attemt a merge, editing code what I want it to look like, setting the stage for more conflicts (see next point)
- git applies commit hash8, which conflict with the edits done in the merge
- I attempt a merge... etc etc

Question: How do I get git to apply all the reverts in a row before presenting any possible conflicts to me?

Answer (score 12):

## Sanity check

First, note that `git revert` reverts your patches in the order you list their hashes; you need to list the hashes from newest to oldest, since you want to proceed backwards in time.  So, I'm going to call your hashes

```
<hash1> ... <hashN>
```

where `<hash1>` is older than `<hash2>` ... is older than `<hashN>`.  So, make sure you were doing

```
git revert <hashN> ... <hash1>
```

in the first place!

## Easy solution

Second, assuming you had been reverting them in the right order, try the `--no-commit` option:

```
git revert --no-commit <hashN> ... <hash1>
```

## More involved solution

Third, If the easy solution doesn't work well, but the commits you want to revert really do make sense as a single commit (if not I don't see much hope), then try this: build one big commit out of the four you want to revert, and then revert the big commit.

1. Build the big commit:

   Create a branch at the parent of the oldest commit:

   ```
   git checkout -b big-commit <hash1>~
   ```

   Copy the commits on your new branch and collapse them:

   ```
   git cherry-pick --no-commit <hash1> ... <hashN>
   git commit -m "Big commit"
   ```

   You should now have one big commit on your branch `big-commit`.
2. Apply the big commit in reverse to the branch you're trying to revert:

   ```
   git checkout <branch you wanted to revert on>
   git revert big-commit
   ```

## Another relatively easy solution

Use selective rebasing to rebuild the branch in question as if it never contained the unwanted commits:

1. Create a new `rebuild` branch to work in:

   ```
   git checkout -b rebuild <branch you want to revert>
   ```
2. Interactively rebase, dropping the commits you don't want:

   ```
   git rebase -i <hash1>~
   ```

   In the interactive rebase editor, delete the lines for `<hash1>` ... `<hashN>`.

Now your `rebuild` branch will contain `<branch you want to revert>`, as though `<hash1>` ... `<hashN>` never existed.  If you run into conflicts here it would seem they're unavoidable.

If you need your work to be on `<branch you want to revert>`, and you can't just `git reset` it to point to your new `rebuild` branch:

```
git checkout <branch you want to revert>
git reset --hard rebuild
```

(e.g. because you've already pushed it publicly), then you can instead apply the differences to `<branch you want to revert>` as a patch:

```
git co <branch you want to revert>    
git diff <branch you want to revert> rebuild | patch
```

Comment: I'm curious - wouldn't using the cherry-pick command in this situation still generate merge conflicts that need to be manually resolved as each commit is applied? I thought the OP is trying to avoid doing procedural merging tasks.

Comment: @miqid: good question! I was assuming the commits themselves were locally compatible / could be applied in order from some starting point without conflict.  If that's not the case, I see no hope of avoiding the conflicts.

Comment: In fact before the merge I tried a cherry-pick too. The result was roughly the same -- I found myself resolving conflicts for no apparent reason.

Comment: @BenjaminBurkhart: did you try the `--no-commit` flag with `git revert` or `git cherry-pick`?  I have another idea; I'll add it above ...